# How to group by all columns except a few in Python?

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I want to group by several columns (around 40) and apply an aggregated sum. The 40 columns are the last 40 columns of the dataset. I haven't found an elegant way to do this.

I tried to group by all columns after the 'column_before' column.

```
df.groupby('grouping_variable')['column_before':].sum()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

The expected result is a dataframe with the last 40 columns aggregated with respect to 'grouping_variable' as a sum

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve it in various ways:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
     'col_to_group': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A'],
     'col_1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a'],
     'col_2': ['x', 'y', 'y', 'y','x'],
     'col_3': [.1, .2, .1, .9, .7],
     'col_4': [.1, .2, .1, .9, .7],
})


df.groupby('col_to_group')['col_3', 'col_4'].sum()
```

Just by selecting part of columns list (slice operator):

```
df.groupby('col_to_group')[df.columns[3:]].sum()
df.groupby('col_to_group')[df.columns[:2:-1]].sum().iloc[:, ::-1]
```

Using name of column `'col_3'` with `iloc`:

```
df.groupby('col_to_group')[df.loc[:, 'col_3':].columns].sum()
```

Simlarly like in list selection but with `iloc`:

```
df.groupby('col_to_group')[df.iloc[:, 3:].columns].sum()
df.groupby('col_to_group')[df.iloc[:, :2:-1].columns].sum().iloc[:, ::-1]
```

Result:

```
              col_3  col_4
col_to_group              
A               1.0    1.0
B               1.0    1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to define the columns you want to group over using list comprehension.

Lets say you want to group over everything but `col_a` and `col_b`. Perhaps you want to sum over those. You can do like this

```
sum_cols = ['col_a', 'col_b']
sums = df.groupby([c for c in df.columns if c not in sum_cols])[sum_cols].sum()
```